# Typescript function seemingly erroneously returning undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following files:

`abstractfoo.ts`:

```
export abstract class AbstractFoo {
    public constructor() {
        throw new Error("I am not instantiable");
    }

    public static foo(param: string) {
        const str = this.plzOverrideMe();
        console.log(str);
        console.log(param);
    }

    protected static plzOverrideMe(): string {
        throw new Error("An override of this function is required");
    }
};
```

`concretefoo.ts`:

```
import { AbstractFoo } from "./abstractfoo"

class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {
    public static override foo(param: string) {
        super.foo(param);
    }

    protected static override plzOverrideMe() {
        return "blah";
    }
};

export default ConcreteFoo.foo;
```

`voodoo.ts`:

```
import voodoo from "./concretefoo"

voodoo("whatisthis")
```

`tsc` happily compiles these files with no errors. However, it crashes at runtime:

```
var str = this.plzOverrideMe();
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plzOverrideMe')
```

I'm not sure what I'm even looking for. Why is it `undefined`, and what can I do to get it to return the string i want?

Comment: In Javascript, `static` methods are accessed via the class name, not via an object instance.  So, `this.plzOverrideMe()` where `this` is an object instance will not have a `plzOverrideMe` method and thus it will be `undefined`.  So, unless TypeScript somehow has completely different rules than JS, you will need to use the Class name instead of `this`.  Note in this [TypeScript example](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-static-methods-and-properties/) how the class name is used to reference static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as TS is concerned, `ConcreteFoo.foo` is type `(param: string) => void`. There is no [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters), so TypeScript doesn't check that.
If you give your method a `this` parameter, [then it'll error as expected:](https://tsplay.dev/mpLbxm):

```
public static override foo(this: typeof ConcreteFoo, param: string) {
```

To make it work at runtime, [you'll need to use `bind`:](https://tsplay.dev/m3XeEW)

```
export default ConcreteFoo.foo.bind(ConcreteFoo);
```

which you can read more about [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).